# Passing a mutable object to immutable parameter

Tags: objective-c

Let's say I have this method:

```
- (void)test:(NSData *)data;
```

On the calling side, I have this:

```
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:someData];

[self test:data];
```

Does data inside test method become immutable?  If data was changed in the calling side while data inside test method is still being processed, will it effect data inside the test method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP actually had two questions:

1. Does data inside test method become immutable?

   I agree that the answer to this question is No. I also agree that an 'evil' implementation could figure out it **was** mutable and change the data.
2. If data was changed in the **calling** side while data inside test method is still being processed, will it effect data inside the test method?

   The answer to that question, I believe, is **Yes**.  The caller of this method knows that `data` is an `NSMutableData`.  If the `test:` method is asynchronous or the caller passes `data` to another asynchronous method before calling `test:` then `data` could be changed while `test` is being executed.

Answer (score 3):

No.

`test:` could check if `[data isKindOfClass:[NSMutableData class]]` and cast it to one, but that's a very bad idea.  `test:` is advertising that it won't mutate the object that is passed in.

Comment: Agree, but it wouldn't be a cast.  Would need to make mutable copy.

Comment: @danh, it would be a cast. If the object is mutable then you just need to tell the compiler it is mutable (because the method definition says it isn't).

Answer (score 2):

No. If the method was to cast the `data` parameter to `NSMutableData` it could edit the data. If you want to ensure that the `data` is immutable you should do:

```
[self test:[data copy]];
```